# Синхронизация двух input по id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, синхронизация

Я хочу синхронизовать два input а по id как это реализовать на javascript не судите строго не знаю js) Заранее спасибо

```
<input type="text" id="1">
<input type="text" id="2">
```

нужно чтобы при вводе данных на input1 данные вписывались и на input 2

Comment: Синхронизация в плане?  input разные бывают. Покажите пример

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <input type="text" id="1"><input type="text" id="2">  нужно чтобы при вводе данных на input 1 данные вписывались и в input 2

Comment: @Ронин , в html файле не должно быть одинаковых id. но разные тоже можно связать.

Comment: у меня же там разные id как их синхронизовать

Answer (score 2):

При событии ввода, копируете значение в элемент с нужным ID:

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" oninput="input2.value = this.value">
<input type="text" id="input2" oninput="input1.value = this.value">
```

Comment: синхронизация сработала спасибо у меня ещё один вопрос как значения input a сохранять в local storage

Comment: @Ронин: другая проблема - другой вопрос. Но, предлагаю воспользоваться поиском - ваши вопросы не уникальны и задавались здесь множество раз.

Comment: у меня есть код сохранения input а но он работает только для одного input после перезагрузки страницы значения второго input а исчезает код сохранения в localstorage и ваш код синхронизация использовал вместе получилось так же значения синхронизируется но после перезагрузки значение второго input исчезает

Comment: @Ронин: что мешает сохранять и восстанавливать значения обоих полей?

Answer (score 0):

Вот написал функцию для 2-ух input.

**Обратите внимание, код не будет работать в stack overflow , но будет у вас**

```js
function connectInp(input1,input2){////// Функция получает на вход селекторы
  const elemInp1 = document.querySelector(input1);
  const elemInp2 = document.querySelector(input2);/////// получаем элементы по этим селекторам
  if(window.localStorage.getItem('value')){
     elemInp1.value = window.localStorage.value
     elemInp2.value = window.localStorage.value
  }
     
  const changeData = function(){ ///// функция обмена данными между ними
    if(this === elemInp1){
      elemInp2.value = elemInp1.value
    }else{
      elemInp1.value = elemInp2.value
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem('value',this.value)
  }
  elemInp1.addEventListener('input',changeData);
  elemInp2.addEventListener('input',changeData);///// прикручиваем событие input к функции обмена данными
}

connectInp('#inp1','#inp2')/// вызываем функцию синхронизации
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp1">
<input type="text" id="inp2">
```

Comment: синхронизация сработала спасибо у меня ещё один вопрос как значения input a сохранять в local storage

Comment: @Ронин , я переписал. Если вам помогло ставьте галочку на ответ.